# list com ports available in VBscript or HTML

Tags: html, com, vbscript

Hi I am running a simple VBscript program which sends a signal to a com port which is made by a USB>serial converter.  This number changes each time I plug it in, and for ease of use I'd like an interactive window to popup with the available com ports rather than making the user look them up and type them in manually.

I was wondering if there was a way to get the available com ports using a VBscript or HTML code then feed it to a radio button option in a ie window.  I've seen several instances on how to get it with C#, but want to keep this code using VBscript and HTML.

Right now I am using devcon to get the information in a CMD window, but I don't know how to port it back to my script.

```
Set objShell = wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strCommand = "elevate cmd /k c:/devcon listclass PORTS"
objShell.Run strcommand, 1, true
```

I tried using > to write the information to a text file, but it ignores that part of the script for some reason...  and attempts to send the command through .sendkeys has failed too .sendkeys doesn't work with windows8 cmd.

Comment: You want to get information about available COM ports from the user's computer?

Comment: yes, I want the program to list the available com ports on the machine its running on.  I'll update the question for clarity

Comment: No. Not without using an activex control.

Comment: ... or shelling out to something like [`devcon`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers.  Could you type of a quick code to show how that would work?  That looks like what I want to do...

Comment: Please see [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/087b4d73-4a5e-4746-b365-ad682911360e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Run` method doesn't give you access to the output of the command. Use the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set devcon = sh.Exec("elevate cmd /k c:/devcon listclass PORTS")

Do While devcon.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

If devcon.ExitCode = 0 Then WScript.Echo devcon.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Answer (score 0):

And for me (on Win 10) only this works:

```
Set devcon = sh.Exec("c:/devcon listclass PORTS")
```